# Refresh Model After Closing Modal Dialog in Ionic-Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am writing an Ionic app, and I want to run a function to refresh the view's model whenever the view becomes visible. I use `$ionicView.enter` in my parent view's controller to load the model normally like so:

```
//Code in Parent View's Controller
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
    loadModel();
});
```

On the view I have a button to open an ionic modal dialog that has its own controller where the user can add a new entry to the main view's model. After the user saves the new entry, I close the modal and would like for the model to automatically be refreshed like so:

```
//Code in Modal Dialog's Controller
$scope.addEntry = function() {
    //code to add new data to model

    //need to call loadModel() in parent controller here
    $scope.modal.hide();

};
```

The event in the parent view's controller does not fire after the modal dialog is closed. What is the best way to call `loadModel()` in the parent view's controller from the modal dialog's controller?

Comment: Did you try listening to `modal.hidden` event ?

Comment: What about a custom broadcast of your own app event?